# mock pysftp connection in pytest

Tags: python-3.x, mocking, pytest, python-unittest

I have a function that connects to the SFTP server with the credentials from the AWS secret manager, reads a file, and returns a dataframe. I'm trying to write a unit test for it. Is there a way to mock a SFTP server with a username and password and upload a file so that I can test the whole flow?

Comment: If you are working with AWS using `boto3` have a have a look at [`moto`](https://github.com/getmoto/moto)